# How can I install latest gnome default icons on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, 17.04

I do not like the look of Ubuntu's default icons and would prefer Gnome's latest icon theme instead. How can I get it on my Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command

```
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme
```

or

```
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

to get the latest gnome icon theme.